# How to implement pull-down refresh and pull-up loading (iOS style)?

Tags: flutter, pull-to-refresh

I'm working with flutter `ListView`. I want to add an iOS pull-down refresh and pull-up loading more style(The two have the same) in my app. I have found `RefreshIndicator class` but the style isn't what I want(it seems to be an android style). I also tried [pull_to_refresh](https://pub.dev/packages/pull_to_refresh). but it seems to be difficult to adjust to the same. So is there any helpful class I can use?

[image: what I want]

what I have done is below:

```
SmartRefresher(
          enablePullDown: true,
          enablePullUp: true,
          header: WaterDropHeader(),
          footer: CustomFooter(
            builder: (BuildContext context,LoadStatus mode){
              Widget body ;
              if(mode==LoadStatus.idle){
                body =  Text("pull up load");
              }
              else if(mode==LoadStatus.loading){
                body =  Container();
              }
              else if(mode == LoadStatus.failed){
                body = Text("Load Failed!Click retry!");
              }
              else if(mode == LoadStatus.canLoading){
                body = Text("release to load more");
              }
              else{
                body = Text("No more Data");
              }
              return Container(
                height: 55.0,
                child: Center(child:body),
              );
            },
          ),
          child: ListView.builder(
            itemBuilder: (c, i) => Card(child: Center(child: Text(items[i]))),
            itemExtent: 100.0,
            itemCount: items.length,
          ),
          controller: _refreshController,
          onRefresh: _onRefresh,
          onLoading: _onLoading,
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a pull-down refresh widget with custom loading indicator by using 'custom_refresh_indicator' package.
https://pub.dev/packages/custom_refresh_indicator